# Python Pandas: Conditional subraction of data between two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to use conditional subtraction between two dataframes.

Dataframe `df1` has columns name and `price.name` is not unique.

```
>>df1
        name   price
    0  mark     50
    1  mark     200
    2  john     10
    3  chris    500
```

Another dataframe has two columns `name` and `paid`, Here `name` is unique

```
>>df2
       name      paid
    0  mark     150
    1  john     10
```

How can I conditionally subtract both dataframes to get following output

Final Output expected

```
       name     price  paid
    0  mark     50     50
    1  mark     200    100
    2  john     10     10
    3  chris    500     0
```

Comment: How would you try it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# mapper for paid values
s = df2.set_index('name')['paid']

df1['paid'] = (df1
      .groupby('name')['price']  # for each name
      .apply(lambda g: g.cumsum()  # sum the total owed
                        .clip(upper=s.get(g.name, default=0)) # in the limit of the paid
                        .pipe(lambda s: s.diff().fillna(s))   # compute reverse cumsum
            )
     )
```

output:

```
    name  price   paid
0   mark     50   50.0
1   mark    200  100.0
2   john     10   10.0
3  chris    500    0.0
```

Comment: Nice! I think OP wants the `0` so no need of `replace` IIUC

Comment: @user2246849 you're right! I swear I had seen a NaN :p (damn brain!)